# Simple 3D Graphics in Python

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, simulation

I am working in a project where 3D visualizations are important to see what is happening during the setup stage and perhaps for visual validation by making a short videos of what is happening.

The problem that I have is that 3D visualizations in Python are too sophisticated, and complicated to learn for what I need. I find that Mathematica is the perfect kind of software...but it is not portable and is very expensive.

## Question

Is there any Python package similar to Mathematica?

### Clarification

I don't want a "plotting" program, since plotting is not what I am looking for. I want to generate simple geometric shapes like spheres and cubes that can move around, this is more than enough. Give some coordinates, perhaps a rotation, and the program just shows the desired image(s) to export as a *.png* or make a quick video; as in Mathematica. 

Packages like Pygame, Panda3D, Pyglet, etc., look too complicated and an overkill for what I need, as well as software like Blender, etc. Jupyter notebooks are similar, but they don't have the 3D graphics capabilities. I found a Python module named *Fresnel*, but it looks too sophisticated for what I need.

I have read several answers to this question here in Stack Overflow, but they seem outdated and not really what I am looking for.

### Further Clarification

To draw spheres in Mathematica you do:

```
coordinates = Flatten[Table[Table[Table[ {i,j,k}, {k,1,10}], {j,1,10}], {i,1,10}],1]
spheres= Flatten[Table[Graphics3D[{Sphere[coordinates[[i]],0.5]}],{i,1,Length[coordinates]}]]
Show[{spheres}]
```

This is a simple quick and easy way of displaying a group of spheres. To use any program in Python to do the same, it seems like you must be an expert in 3D graphics to do this simple thing.

Programs that have capabilities of using Python scripts, like Blender, make it difficult to use the interface in a straight forward way (try doing the same in Blender, it will take a while just to learn the basics!).

Comment: `vpython` https://vpython.org/ ?

Comment: Can you show an example of what do you want?

Comment: Blender may be overkill in the sense that it can do way more than you want. But for what you said, you could do that in seconds in blender even with beginner level proficiency

Comment: @Epsi95, thank you. Looks like a simple and good program. Had never heard about it. Going to give it a shot.

Comment: @Alderven, I have provided an example if you need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DerekEden, I have sincerely tried, but the interface for Python scripts is extremely complicated; or so I find it.

Comment: @AndrésGarcíaEscovar I agree - the scripting environment is absolutely terrible in Blender..like embarassing..but if you can do what you're trying to do in the GUI - you can hover over every button, and get copy the code into a script easily that way..there's also a macro tracing add-on where you can record operations and turn them into macro buttons

Comment: @AndrésGarcíaEscovar if you want to go down the Blender route, this could help with python development in a real IDE https://chrisconlan.com/best-way-develop-blender-python-add-ons/

Comment: Forgot to mention. Paraview  is also very simple to use, and can be scripted in python as well

Comment: Apparently, SO is going the way of Wikipedia, with commissars policing content for conformance to rules, rather than for usefulness.  To save...uh, electrons, I guess?  I've deleted my suggestion of pi3d accordingly, but take the chance of repeating it here.  Feel free to email me to discuss particulars (ketil at malde org) - or to suggest alternative venues where discussing it is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know several other user-friendly plotting libraries than matplotlib, but not a lot provide an interactive view. There is of course the well known [vtk](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/GeometricObjects/ColoredLines/) but it's not for end-user

### plotly

For usage in a notebook, like jupyter and mathematica, you probably would go for [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/3d-line-plots/) It's using a browser-based interface with plots very similar to mathematica

[image: plotly 3D plot example]

### pymadcad

If you need a more offline version and what you are looking for is some view you can rotate/zoom/pan to look on your geometry by different sides, you can take a look at [pymadcad](https://pymadcad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html)
It even works with touchscreens.
It is not centered on 3D visualization, so it's a bit overkill to use it only for it, but for 3D curves, 3D surfaces, spheres and cubes as you said, it can do the job

simple plots with pymadcad:

```py
from madcad import *
from madcad.rendering import Displayable
from madcad.displays import GridDisplay

# create a wire from custom points
s = 100
mycurve = Wire([  vec3(sin(t/s), cos(t/s), 0.1*t/s)
                  for t in range(int(s*6*pi)) ])

# create a sphere
mysphere = uvsphere(vec3(0), 0.5)

# display in a separated window
show([
       mycurve,   # displaying the curve
       mysphere,  # displaying the sphere
       Displayable(GridDisplay, vec3(0)),   # this is to have a 2D grid centered on origin
       ])
```

result: [image: result window]
(The window is dark because so is my system theme, but likely it will adapt to yours)